Nuxtjsのソースでブレイクポイントが貼れない
Nuxtjsのバージョンは@nuxt/cli v2.14.12を使用しています。
アプリの構成は以下のような構成で複数のvue、jsがあります。
MyAPP
│  nuxt.config.js
│  package-lock.json
│  package.json
│          
├─.vscode
│      launch.json
│      
├─node_modules
│          
├─src
│  ├─assets
│  │  │ 
│  │              
│  ├─common
│  │  │  Util.js

│  │          
│  ├─components
│  │  │  
│  │  └─parts
│  │          XXXX.vue
│  │          
│  ├─layouts
│  │      default.vue
│  │      
│  ├─pages
│  │      index.vue
│  │      
│  ├─plugins
│  │  │  xxx.js
│  │  │  
│  │  ├─axios
│  │  │  │  axios.js
│  │                 
│  └─store
│      │  
│      └─types
│              actionTypes.js
│              getterTypes.js
│              index.js
│              moduleTypes.js
│              mutationTypes.js

まずはVSCodeでブレイクポイントがはれないか、以下サイトを参考に
Nuxt.js を VS Code上でデバッグする方法 - Qiita
package.json、launch.jsonを用意し、VSCodeのデバッグで「Full-stack」を実施しましたが「Launch via NPM」が失敗し、Chromeは起動するものの、以下のエラーで画面が表示されません。
このサイトにアクセスできません localhost で接続が拒否されました。

直接ターミナルでnpm run debugコマンドを実行しても以下のような結果が返ってきています。
package.jsonの"debug"の指定が誤っていますでしょうか？
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! llx_nuxt_spa@1.0.0
debug: `node --inspect-brk=9229 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt` npm ERR!
Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

package.json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt-ts",
    "build": "nuxt-ts build",
    "start": "nuxt-ts start",
    "debug": "node --inspect-brk=9229 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt"
  },

.vscode\launch.json
{

  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "debug"],
      "sourceMaps": true
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeArgs": [
          "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ],
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
      }
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Full-stack",
      "configurations": ["Launch via NPM", "Launch Chrome"]
    }
  ]
}

npm run dev コマンドを実行した場合、Chromeで http://localhost:3000 を実行すると画面は表示されます。
chrome開発ツールのソースタブで確認すると webpack://配下に期待するsrcフォルダやその配下のフォルダ、vueファイルが見えるのですが、なぜか同じvueファイル名が分割されて複数表示されています。
そのファイルに対し、ブレイクポイントを試してみましたが期待するところに貼れません。
またsrcフォルダと同じ並び（webpack://直下）にもvueファイルが表示されており、こちらはvueファイルが分割されておらず、１つずつしか表示されていませんが、やはりブレイクポイントが晴れない状態です。
VSCodeのデバッグもしくは開発ツールのデバッグをするうえで何か必要な設定がありますでしょうか？

お使いの設定にいくつか問題があるように見受けられますので、ステップバイステップで解決策をご提案いたします。
まず、package.jsonの"debug"スクリプトに関してですが、Nuxt.jsのデバッグコマンドにはdevコマンドを指定する必要があります。現在の設定ではNuxtが正しく起動しないため、以下のように修正してください：
"debug": "node --inspect-brk=9229 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt dev"

次に、VSCodeのlaunch.json設定についてですが、設定自体は問題なさそうです。しかし、sourceMapPathOverridesの部分で、ソースマップが正しく解決されていない可能性があります。Webpackの設定に依存するため、実際にソースマップが生成されているパスを確認し、必要に応じてパスの設定を調整してください。
また、Chrome開発ツールでVueファイルが正しく表示されていない問題については、Webpackのソースマップが原因であることが多いです。特にVueファイルが分割されて表示される場合、それはソースマップの問題が高いと考えられます。この問題を解決するには、Nuxtのビルド設定でソースマップの生成方法を調整するか、またはVueファイルが正しくマッピングされていることを確認してください。
最後に、VSCodeとChromeの両方でブレイクポイントが正常に機能しない場合は、デバッグセッションを完全にリセットし、再度設定を確認することが有効です。時にはVSCodeを再起動するだけで問題が解消されることもあります。

ありがとうございます。まずご指摘いただいたpackage.jsonを見直してみます。
